# Trying to add multiple videos to a YouTube playlist from .csv file

Tags: python, csv, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to add a list of video IDs stored in a .csv file to a playlist using the `youtube-api.`

I have got as far as adding a single video, but I am struggling to import a list of video IDs stored in a CSV file.

So within this snippet I would like to replace the video ID with a link to a CSV file:

```
def add_video_to_playlist(youtube, videoID, playlistID):
    add_video_request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
    part = "snippet",
    body = {
             'snippet': {
              'playlistId': 'PLpB9AHGzZKOugx13Kwkj47mro_PftxSE9',
              'resourceId': {
                  'kind': 'youtube#video',
                  'videoId': 'tcJ4eVVK640'`
```

This is the full code as far as I have got:

```
import httplib2
import os
import sys
import csv

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run


# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file
# that containsthe OAuth 2.0 information for this application,
# including its client_id and client_secret. You can acquire
# an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the Google
# Cloud Console at https://cloud.google.com/console.
#
# Please ensure that you have enabled the
# YouTube Data API for your project.
#
# For more information about using OAuth2 to
# access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
#
# For more information about the client_secrets.json
# file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
#
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = ""

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

%s

with information from the Cloud Console
https://cloud.google.com/console

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                           CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


def get_authenticated_service():
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
                                   scope=YOUTUBE_SCOPE,
                                   message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run(flow, storage)

    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                 http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def add_video_to_playlist(youtube, videoID, playlistID):
    add_video_request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part = "snippet",
               body = {
                   'snippet': {
                       'playlistId': 'PlayistId',
                       'resourceId': {
                           'kind': 'youtube#video',
                           '     videoId': 'VideoId'
                       }
                       #'position': 0
                   }
               }
    ).execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube = get_authenticated_service()
    add_video_to_playlist(youtube, "yszl2oxi8IY", "PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-    J8funQ")
```

Comment: There are unexpected multiple whitespaces in two places: in the string near `videoId` in function `add_video_to_playlist()`: `'     videoId': 'VideoId'` (but only in the full code part) and the string `"PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-    J8funQ"`

Answer (score 0):

If your method for adding one video works, you should keep it the way it is. No need to re-write it on that front. Instead, you'll basically be iterating over a list of `videoID`s and calling `add_video_to_playlist` multiple times.

For that, the basic concept is:

```
 for video_id in list_of_video_ids:
      add_video_to_playlist(youtube,video_id,playlistID)
```

From there, you work backwards and build your `list_of_video_ids` by iterating through the rows of the csv file:

```
 import csv

 with open('path/to/file.csv', 'w') as file:
      reader = csv.reader(file)
      list_of_video_ids = []
      for row in reader:
           list_of_video_ids.append(row[0]) # assuming your video IDs
                                            # are in the first column
                                            # of each row

 for video_id in list_of_video_ids:
      ... # so on and so forth
```

`csv.reader()` creates a reader object. By iterating over this object, you access each row of the file in sequence, grabbing each column using the numbered index.

You can also use `csv.DictReader()`. Iterating over this creates rows as dicts, with the values in the first row of the file being the keys for those columns. So, if the first cell in the column was titled `video_id`, you would access the cell using `row['video_id']`.

If you're looking for something more specific, let me know. This is a general overview.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

import httplib2
from oauth2client import tools
import os
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))


def get_authenticated_service(flags):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
                                   scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE,
                                   message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                 http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


def list_playlist_items(youtube, playlistID):
    playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        playlistId=playlistID,
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=50
    )

    while playlistitems_list_request:
        playlistitems_list_response = playlistitems_list_request.execute()

        # Print information about each video.
        for playlist_item in playlistitems_list_response["items"]:
            title = playlist_item["snippet"]["title"]
            video_id = playlist_item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]
            print "%s (%s)" % (title, video_id)

        playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
            playlistitems_list_request, playlistitems_list_response)


def add_video_to_playlist(youtube, videoID, playlistID):
    playlistitems_insert_request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
            'snippet': {
                'playlistId': playlistID,
                'resourceId': {
                    'kind': 'youtube#video',
                    'videoId': videoID

                }
                # 'position': 0
            }
        }
    ).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        parents=[tools.argparser])
    flags = parser.parse_args()
    youtube = get_authenticated_service(flags)
    playlistID = "YOUR PLAYLIST ID"
    videoIDs = [
        "-xhJx6UR4Vw", "04mfKJWDSzI", "MORE VIDEO IDS"
    ]
    for videoID in videoIDs:
        add_video_to_playlist(youtube, videoID, playlistID)
    list_playlist_items(youtube, playlistID)
```

Please note that you need to create a project in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), enable the YouTube Data API, add new credentials (of type OAuth 2.0 Client ID --> Web Application, with an authorized Redirect URL of http://localhost:8080/ added), download the client_secrets.json file and put it in the same directory.

Good luck :)

Comment: What did you change? E.g. I noticed you fixed the multiple whitespace in the string near `videoId` in `add_video_to_playlist()`: `'     videoId': 'VideoId'`